# How can I gain access to the Facebook access_token issued when authenticating with Waterlock for Sails?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sails.js, facebook-access-token, waterlock

I am using Waterlock to authenticate users in my Sails.js backend API for a mobile app that I am building.  I think I'm experiencing a bug that isn't allowing me to save additional user data from Facebook such as email, profile picture, friend list, etc.

Regardless of whether this is because of my own error, I would prefer to make calls of my own to the Facebook graph API so that I can add the data to my own model but I can't figure out how to get my hands on the user token.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.